count and group by two columns in a table
I have a table that looks like this:



c1
c2




foo
bar


bar
nerd


bar
bar


foo
nerd


tick
tock



I want a query that will group by both r1 and r2 and count all occurrences. I want the output to look like this:



r1
count




foo
2


bar
4


tick
1


tock
1


nerd
1



Thanks!
I tried a union all but got lost.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Use a union approach with aggregation:
SELECT r1, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT c1 AS r1 FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c2 FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY r1;

